# JS classList.add and classList.remove not functioning in my popup html/css

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, popupwindow, simplemodal

so i am trying to create a html popup using CSS for styling and javascript for the popup motion. However, it's my first time using VS code to do it but somehow, it doesn't function.

Please help.

```
document.getElementById("open-popup-button");
document.addEventListener("click",function(){document.getElementsByClassName("popup")[0].classList.add("active")});

document.getElementById("dismiss-popup-button");
document.addEventListener("click",function(){document.getElementsByClassName("popup")[0].classList.remove("active")});
```

Comment: We need to see the relevant HTML and CSS. Also [don't use `getElementsByClassName()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474). Also, are you getting any errors in your developer console (F12)?

Comment: Can you show your HTML with that button and popup?

Comment: The event listener should be attached to the element that you are getting by id, not to the whole document.
`let openButton = document.getElementById("open-popup-button");
openButton.addEventListener("click",function(){document.getElementsByClassName("popup")[0].classList.add("active")});


let closeButton = document.getElementById("dismiss-popup-button");
closeButton.addEventListener("click",function(){document.getElementsByClassName("popup")[0].classList.remove("active")});`

Comment: Lines 1 and 3 of your code effectively do nothing. The scan the DOM for matching elements and then don't do anything with those element references.

Comment: @ScottMarcus no errors but the code that dawalberto suggested worked perfectly